# Android - automatically start a service when joining a specific wifi network

Tags: android, service, wifi

I am trying to build an application/service that will execute some coding everytime I connect to a specific wifi network (to log into that network and then keep the connection active ). I do already have the code for the login part and it is working fine, but I don't really know how I can automatically run this code when I connect to a network.

Ideally, I would like to build a service that starts when I join a specific wifi network, keeps the connection active (like makes a request every 10 min to keep the connection active) and finally stops when I leave that network.

I know how to build the service and keep it active, but don't know how to start and stop it automatically when joining / leaving a wifi network. Any suggestions on how to do this is appreciated. If my approach is not correct and there is a better/simpler way to do that, please let me know

Regards,

Marcel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need a broadcast receiver.
this broadcast receiver will receives broadcasts of Wifi connected and wifi disconnected actions and from there you can start and stop your service.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, registering a broadcast receiver on "android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" did the trick. I then use a WifiManager to get the SSID and start my service.

Answer (score 0):

Implement a [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) listening for the scan results from `WifiManager.startScan()`

Have a look at [Android Scan for Wifi networks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3456770/432903)